# How can I not send form when press button inside form?

Tags: primefaces

I have primefaces form

```
<h:form id="profileGridForm">
<h:panelGroup>
                        <p:inplace id="myid" editor="#{bean.changeLangEnabled}">
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.changedBillingLanguage}">
                                ...
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:inplace>
                    </h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup>
                        <p:commandButton value="Model" update="modelForm" action="#{modelBean.clear}" ajax="true"
                                         oncomplete="PF('showModel').show()"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

When I press Model button call ChangedBillingLanguage method. How can I not send form when press button inside form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Comment: So not submit any values? See the duplicate... (or check the PrimeFaces documentation and showcase)

Comment: ... use `process="@none"`, or in your case `process="@this"`